# Passing parameter to a Stored Procedure with VIEWS?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a VIEW where I am trying to pass 2 date parameters, however, I know that is not doable. For now the VIEW uses 2 hardcoded dates ' between '1/1/2015' and 12/1/2015'. What I need to do populates a table with the data from the view, however, having it filter by those two dates. The dates will be entered by the user in the VB application. So for now I have

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[spCompanyInfo]
AS
@FromDate
@ToDate
Insert into tblTempTable(companyID, companyName, TotalBegInv)
Select CompanyID, CompanyName, TotalBegInv
From vCompanyInfo
```

I'm not sure if I can leave the dates as they are in the VIEW or if need to do it some other way. Also, how would I go about selecting data from vCompanyInfo that is filtered with FROM and TO dates.

EDITED:

I'm trying to replicate a report from ACCESS to SQL-SERVER. In ACCESS I previously had multiple queries that I used to create one FINAL QUERY and generate the report. I'm trying to do the same with SQL SERVER. Because I don't have extensive knowledge of it, I tried to do it with the same ideaology, by using views. So I replicated the views and made one FINAL view. I'm trying to pull data from it, until I came across the problem that I couldn't use parameters in VIEWS.

Comment: Smell like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass parameter to a view, you have to go with table valued UDF instead if you want to pass parameters. Otherwise you need to have all column available to a view on which you want to apply filters.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO tblTempTable (companyID,companyName,TotalBegInv)
    SELECT CompanyID,
           CompanyName,
           TotalBegInv
    FROM   vCompanyInfo
    WHERE  SomeColumn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

If somecolumn is not available in vCompanyInfo definition, then you have to use underline query and can either create a new view with this column or create a UDF or stored proc to pass parameters

Answer (score 2):

Views don't have parameters. Your procedure that selects data out of the view can use the parameters in a WHERE clause, however.

You haven't specified the name of the column which your date parameters are meant to filter, and you have made a few other syntax errors, but I think this is a rough approximation of what you are looking for:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Spcompanyinfo]
(
  @FromDate DATETIME,
  @ToDate   DATETIME
)
AS
    INSERT INTO tblTempTable (companyID,companyName,TotalBegInv)
    SELECT CompanyID,
           CompanyName,
           TotalBegInv
    FROM   vCompanyInfo
    WHERE  SomeColumn BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
```

Comment: What would I put in my view? Would I not filter it at all? Basically I'm using two date in my filter right now. This query looks similar to what I'd do in Access. I'm looking for data for SOLD items. So I have a column in my VIEW that is SUM of SOLD items, and another column that is not visible is TransactionDate where (FILTER) Between 1/1/2015 and 12/1/2015. So my question is do I not include any hardcoded dates in the VIEW?

Comment: You can include hard coded dates if it adds value.  For example if you want to set a lower and upper limit within which values could be returned.  Those hard coded limits would be COMBINED with any filtering applied in the SP.  If you want the full range of values to be searchable then leave the view without a filter.

Comment: If the view only exists to provide data to this SP you could move the view logic into the SP, and drop the view.  When @Serpiton mentioned XY this is what s/he was talking about.  Without context it's hard to provide good advice.